# Utilize user input in SQL query

Tags: php, sql, where-clause

I'm trying to update a table given user input. Once the user hits submit on the form, I want the WHERE portion of my query to reflect the zip code entered by the user. Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<form id="user-location" method="post" action="#">
      <input id="addressInput" name="addressInput" type="text">
      <input id="submit" onclick="searchLocations()" value="GO" type="button">
</form>
```

---

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","######","######","######");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Prospects WHERE zip = 'echo $_POST['addressInput']'");

echo "<table width='540' cellpadding='0' border='0' cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
<th>Under 4</th>
<th>5 - 9</th>
<th>10 - 14</th>
<th>15 - 17</th>
<th>18 - 20</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['cy_pop_04'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['cy_pop_59'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['cy_pop_1014'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['cy_pop_1517'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['cy_pop_1820'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `WHERE zip = '$_POST[addressInput]'` and not `WHERE zip = 'echo $_POST['addressInput']'` plus, you shouldn't be using this method; you're open to SQL injection; use prepared statements. Make sure you also have a valid JS function for your `searchLocations()`

Comment: use `$zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['addressInput'])` and use `WHERE zip = '$zip'` at-least if not using prepare statements.

Comment: See [`this link`](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/PHP-5:-MySQLi-Prepared-Statements/41452) on using prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I made those changes but it doesn't seem to be updating my table. Is my submit button correct? (I removed the searchLocations() as well)

Comment: You're welcome. Are you using both your form and PHP inside the same page? @user2155400 If so, change `<input id="submit" onclick="searchLocations()" value="GO" type="button">` to `<input id="submit" value="GO" type="submit">` then use a conditional statement.

Comment: Also, you say it's not updating your table. That's because you're not doing an INSERT or UPDATE. You're only doing a SELECT @user2155400 In your case, since you're using a WHERE clause, you need to use UPDATE and you need to choose which column to UPDATE.

Comment: I posted something for you below using prepared statements instead. @user2155400

Answer (score 1):

Change `<input id="submit" onclick="searchLocations()" value="GO" type="button">` to `<input id="submit" value="GO" type="submit" name="submit">` then use a conditional statement.

I.e.: `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Here is a prepared statement method.

The way you're doing it now (*or intended to use*), will leave you open to [`SQL injection`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","######","######","######");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$zip = $_POST['addressInput'];

if($query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM Prospects WHERE zip=?")){
    $query->bind_param("s", $zip);
    $query->execute();
}

echo "<table width='540' cellpadding='0' border='0' cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
<th>Under 4</th>
<th>5 - 9</th>
<th>10 - 14</th>
<th>15 - 17</th>
<th>18 - 20</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['cy_pop_04'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['cy_pop_59'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['cy_pop_1014'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['cy_pop_1517'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['cy_pop_1820'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

} // closing brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

Do not do or use this:

```
WHERE zip = 'echo $_POST['addressInput']'
             ^^^^        ^            ^
```

It's always better using [`prepared statements`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) when using `mysqli_*` functions.

- [`Here is a tutorial`](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/PHP-5:-MySQLi-Prepared-Statements/41452) on using prepared statements.